# Extreme Image Noise Removal

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, noise

I've been trying to solve a noise removal (from images) problem using deep learning and I've tried a lot of the newer architectures for noise removal including FFDNet, NLRN and MWCNN. The problem is, they work fine on images with little noise but if there's an extremely noisy image (like the one attached below), they don't really perform very well.

I've tried retraining MWCNN on a customized noisy dataset but it is really either smoothing images too much or doesn't remove any noise at all. Is there any literature/architecture/pretrained-model available for extreme noise removal?

[image: An example image]